# PyQt5, choice some part of text in inedible mode

Tags: pyqt5

I wanna do a currency converter in python with PyQt5 and i would like do a input field like that :
[exemple of field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlNVg.png) where i can only change the "1" values and where the converted value changes depending on the starting value.

But i struggle to only get "1" editable and other text not editable.

I would like to know we can do it or no thank you ^^
I searched on google, used chatGPt but i didn't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass your QLineEdit and overwrite these two methods from QWidget: focusInEvent and focusOutEvent, in order to handle any user input. You can also store the *current value* (as a float in USD), the *currency unit* (as a string), and the *currency conversion value* (as a float).

Inside `focusInEvent`, it should open the Editor Mode:

1. It should get the *current value* (in USD);
2. Convert the stored value into a string. As a requirement, it should be able to be converted back into a float number somehow;
3. Set this string as the QLineEdit's text.

Inside `focusOutEvent`, it should open the Display Mode:

1. It should get the current number typed by the user;
2. If the number is valid, it should create the display string, which contains:

   1. The *current value*;
   2. The *current converted value*;
   3. The target *currency unit*.
3. It should display this string as the QLineEdit's text.

You can also subclass the QComboBox, though that's optional, and connect a callback to the `currentIndexChanged` signal. You can add items inside them, and as the UserRole of every item, you can set the *conversion value* for that item.

Everytime the user selects a new item in the combobox, this function will be triggered, allowing you to update: the QLineEdit currency unit, it's currency conversion value, and it's display text right after all changes are done.

Here's a working version of the answer:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QComboBox, QLineEdit
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

class ConversionCombo(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__()

        self.editor = editor
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selected)

        self.addItem("USD", 1.0)
        self.addItem("TWD", 28.522505)

    def selected(self, index):
        self.editor.unit = self.itemText(index)
        self.editor.multiplier = self.itemData(index, Qt.UserRole)
        self.editor.refreshDisplay()

class ConversionEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = 1.0
        self.multiplier = 1.0

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        if (self.eventReason(event)):
            self.setText(self.editorText())

        super().focusInEvent(event)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        if (self.eventReason(event)):
            self.value = float(self.text())
            self.refreshDisplay()

        super().focusOutEvent(event)

    def eventReason(self, e):
        return (e.reason() == Qt.MouseFocusReason or e.reason() == Qt.TabFocusReason or e.reason() == Qt.BacktabFocusReason)

    def editorText(self):
        return "{:,.6f}".format(self.value).rstrip('0.')

    def displayText(self):
        return ("${:,.6f} USD = {:,.6f} %s" % self.unit).format(self.value, self.value * self.multiplier)

    def refreshDisplay(self):
        self.setText(self.displayText())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    win = QMainWindow()

    editor = ConversionEdit()
    combo = ConversionCombo(editor)

    widget = QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
    widget.layout().addWidget(combo)
    widget.layout().addWidget(editor)

    win.setCentralWidget(widget)
    win.show()

    app.exec_()
```

---

In order to trigger the `focusInEvent`, click inisde the QLineEdit.

In order to trigger the `focusOutEvent`, click back on the combo box, or use Shift + Tab.